# Get Resource Consumption statistics for a User or Server principal or each Request on Azure dedicated SQL pool using Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am looking for a query on Log Analytics to find Resource Consumption statistics for each request or consolidated request for each login or application on Azure dedicated SQL Pool.

OR

If above isnt queryable, If I can check somehow, On Log Analytics, for how long each User or Service Principal was active for past month on Azure dedicated SQL Pool

This can give me some idea, which user is consuming or querying the pool for longer time.

Thanks in advance for the help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.bradleyschacht.com/log-analytics-with-dedicated-sql-pools-formerly-sql-dw/) third-party article which is showing how to configure Auditing and Diagnostic setting using Log Analytics.

This sample query pulls a few of the relevant columns from the AzureDiagnostics table by narrowing the data down to the ExecRequests Category. This data corresponds to the system DMV sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where Category == "ExecRequests"
| project
    ResourceGroup,
    LogicalServerName_s,
    DatabaseId_d,
    StartTime_t,
    EndCompileTime_t,
    Category,
    Status_s,
    RequestId_s,
    Command_s
| summarize
    ResourceGroup = any(ResourceGroup),
    LogicalServerName = any(LogicalServerName_s),
    DatabaseId = any(DatabaseId_d),
    StartTime = max(StartTime_t),
    EndCompileTime = max(EndCompileTime_t),
    Category = any(Category),
    Status = min(Status_s),
    Command = any(Command_s),
    record_count = count()
    by RequestId_s
```

Comment: This gives results per Query on SQL DW. I there something that gives consolidation of each App/User resource consumption.

I tried this: 
`AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == 'SQLSecurityAuditEvents'
| summarize sum(duration_milliseconds_d), count() by server_principal_name_s, database_principal_name_s
| extend avg_duration_per_session = sum_duration_milliseconds_d/(1000 * count_)
| order by avg_duration_per_session desc
| project database_principal_name_s, server_principal_name_s, count_, sum_duration_milliseconds_d, avg_duration_per_session`

Comment: However, this is also not very accurate.. 
I would like something that combines SQLSecurityAuditEvents and ExecRequests, but dont know on which field I need to do a join